# Updating group without log out or subshell

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, mapreduce

I'm trying to run Docker on Elastic MapReduce streaming but am having trouble with a permissions issue.  In my bootstrap script, I need the "hadoop" user to be part of the "docker" group (as described on the [AWS Docker Basics page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html)):

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker hadoop
```

but I cannot log out or spawn a subshell (with newgrp).  Is there a way to force the group setting to take effect in my current shell session?

Answer (score 0):

No - unless the `hadoop` process is running as root, then you could do some [gdb trickery](https://superuser.com/a/68942/218574) to change the [EUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier), but not the group. But I guess that won't help in your case.

What *could* help is to **temporarily** allow the `hadoop` user access to the files that are meant for the `docker` group to be accessed.

Example: the `hadoop` user needs write-access to the `/foo` directory, but only the `docker` group can currently write it:

```
$ ls -ld /foo/
drwxrwx--- 2 root docker 4096 Mar 10 00:42 /foo/
```

Most file systems support [ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) nowadays:

```
$ sudo setfacl -m g:docker:rwx /foo
```

Now the `hadoop` user will be able to write to `/foo`.

I know, that's not what you asked, but since there's no possibility to change the EGID of a running process, maybe it works the other way around with the help of ACLs.

Comment: Thanks @ckujau - but yeah, it's not just a file permissions thing.  For some reason (that I don't really understand), on Amazon Linux AMI the "docker" command can only be run by members of the "docker" group, otherwise there's a TCP issue or something as the docker client attempts to communicate with the docker engine.

Answer (score -1):

It took me a while to figure out how to run Docker on Hadoop Streaming on EMR. It turns out that the user that runs the job is `yarn` and not `hadoop`. So the bootstrap script needs to have the following lines:

```
sudo useradd -r yarn # create 'yarn' since it does not exist yet
sudo usermod -a -G docker yarn
```

Note, that I manually create `yarn` user because when the bootstrap script runs Hadoop is not installed yet

Comment: This doesn't even address the question

Comment: It addresses the original problem @Max had. The OP was asking a wrong question...